# ADBannerView memory management

Tags: iphone, ads

Is an AdBannerView released when its action has finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that you alloc or init you need to release yourself.

```
[someBanner release];
```

Or you can also use autorelease as well. This releases the object at the end of the method it's created in.

```
SomeObject *object = [[SomeObject alloc] init] autorelease];
```